# How to use ThreadPool and Semaphore at the same time?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I need to write recursive method that get number, decrement it, print it and after pass to the next call of the function. I've managed to do that with Thread join, but how can I implement with thread pool and semaphores for accessing the value?

this is my code of the method with threads:

```
private static void TaskThreadsJoin(int count)
{
    if (count == 1) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Current value is 1");
    }
    else 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Current value is {0}",count-1);
        Thread newThread = new Thread(() => TaskThreadsJoin(count-1));
        newThread.Start();
        newThread.Join();
    }
}
```

Edit:
I've managed to create a recursive function for adding threads in thread pool. However, the output of function is not correct, because it's printing the exit from recursive value twice(the `"ThreadPool Current value is 1"` string). I'm not sure, what can be the problem. This is the code of the method:

```
private static void RecursionTaskWithPools(int count)
{
    if (count == 1)
    {
        semaphoreSlim.Wait();
        Console.WriteLine("ThreadPool Current value is 1");
        semaphoreSlim.Release();
    }
    else
    {
        semaphoreSlim.Wait();
        Console.WriteLine("ThreadPool Current value is {0}", count - 1);
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(x => RecursionTaskWithPools(count-1));
        semaphoreSlim.Release();
    }
}
```

`semaphoreSlim` is a static semaphore object.

Edit 2: I've found the mistake, it was double in the if part of the condition.

Comment: If you aren't doing any CPU bound work, why are you using thread?

Comment: What is it you are really trying to do? Starting a thread and immediately joining is pointless in most circumstances. And you really need to know what you are doing if you are trying to multi thread a recursive function. Chances are that it will not be thread safe, or that the overhead will be larger than any possible gains.

Comment: In fact, recursion isn't a pattern that works with multi-threading in general.

Comment: This is just for homework task.

Comment: I would take a look at [Task.Run](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run?view=net-7.0). This give you an automatic way to handle return values, runs on the thread pool, and has mostly superseded `Thread`. If your teacher insists on pointless examples and outdated patterns he needs to do the teaching himself.

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: I've edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, the output of function is not correct, because it's printing the exit from recursive value twice(the "ThreadPool Current value is 1" string)

Consider what the value would be if the method is called with the count `2`.

```
Console.WriteLine("Current value is {0}",count-1);
```

Would output `"Current value is 1"`, and then call the method again with the the count `1`, this would then fall into the other branch and print `"Current value is 1"`, so it looks like you are printing the same value twice.

It has nothing to do with threadpools or semaphores.  But your two examples are not equivalent, the second one never waits for the started task to complete, and if it *did* wait it would deadlock on the semaphore.

You need to change one of the print-statements, either to print the actual count, not count-1. or to print zero as the final count.

That said, If this is homework I have no idea what this is supposed to teach you. You should never write code like this in real life.